# Error thrown while handling message App\Message\TitleMessage. Removing from transport after 3 retries

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create some task handle by a queue but I'm getting this error

```
[critical] Error thrown while handling message App\Message\TitleMessage. Removing from transport after 3 retries. Error: "No handler for message "App\Message\TitleMessage"."
```

this is the message class

```
<?php

namespace App\Message;


class TitleMessage{
    private $title;

    public function __construct(string $title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function getContent(): string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }
}
```

this is the handler

```
<?php

namespace App\MessageHandler;

use App\Message\TitleMessage;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Attribute\AsMessageHandler;

#[AsMessageHandler]
class TitleMessageHandler{

    public function __invoke(TitleMessage $message)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

at `.env` file

```
MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=doctrine://default
```

and `messages.yml`

```
framework:
    messenger:
        # reset services after consuming messages
        reset_on_message: true

        # Uncomment this (and the failed transport below) to send failed messages to this transport for later handling.
        # failure_transport: failed

        transports:
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#transport-configuration
            async: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
            # failed: 'doctrine://default?queue_name=failed'
            # sync: 'sync://'

        routing:
            # Route your messages to the transports
            'App\Message\TitleMessage': async
```

It's the first time I work with queues on symfony , but I think the handler is setted bt type-hinting on the handle class, I don't know what is wrong

Comment: Hi, is this a Symfony project? Can you include your services definition, or check if you enabled auto-wiring?

Comment: Yes is symfony project

Comment: Can you include your `services.yaml` definitions in your question? I think there might be something wrong with your auto-wiring if your handler is not available.